# How to receive IAM credentials based on AWS Cognito User Pool Access token

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0

Let's say I have an access token of my user. Now I want to initiate a boto3 client with the IAM access rights of that user.

I found out that for an identity pool I could call the get_credentials_for_identity endpoint. But what do I do for a user pool?